# Copy in array (without size)

Tags: arrays, go

I am new to go and I'm trying to extract a bit of specific data (Employee.ID) from an array and insert it into another (new) array.

So far I've had no luck in doing so, the code I use is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Employee struct {
    ID         int64
    Name       string
    Department string
}

func main() {
    employees := []Employee{{1, "Ram", "India"}, {2, "Criest", "Europe"}}
    ids := []int64{}
    for i, v := range employees {
        fmt.Println(i, v)
    }
}
```

In short, I want to extract ID from the `employees` array and copy those to the `ids` array. The size of `employees` array is not fixed at any point in time.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Please note: you're using *slices*, not arrays.

Comment: Thanks, Gavin. I was just carrying legacy terms :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the length of a slice with `len(employees)`. Generally, if you know the size up front, `ids := make([]int64, length)` is preferrable to `ids := []int64{}` because it will result in fewer allocations as the slice grows.

```
ids := make([]int64, len(employees))
for i,e := range employees{
   ids[i] = e.ID
}
```

Or a slightly alternate style:

```
ids := make([]int64, 0, len(employees)) // declare capacity, but not length
for _ , e := range employees{
   ids = append(ids, e.ID)
}
```